# Cannot build go_proto_library with gRPC

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc, bazel

I'm getting started with bazel and trying to generate the protobuf code for golang for an RPC service.

When I try to build it I get the following error:

```
bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/examples/grpc/protos/helloworld_go_proto_/examples/grpc/protos/helloworld.pb.go:229:7: undefined: grpc.ClientConnInterface
bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/examples/grpc/protos/helloworld_go_proto_/examples/grpc/protos/helloworld.pb.go:233:11: undefined: grpc.SupportPackageIsVersion6
bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/examples/grpc/protos/helloworld_go_proto_/examples/grpc/protos/helloworld.pb.go:243:5: undefined: grpc.ClientConnInterface
bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/examples/grpc/protos/helloworld_go_proto_/examples/grpc/protos/helloworld.pb.go:246:26: undefined: grpc.ClientConnInterface
```

Full build log: https://app.buildbuddy.io/invocation/c3773978-22dd-44c8-b977-13967a1953b7

Here is the code: https://github.com/juanique/example-go-grpc. I'm trying to include the least possible amount of code to make that target work.

Since the `BUILD` file was generated by `gazelle` I suspect the issue is in the `WORKSPACE` file: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/juanique/example-go-grpc/main/WORKSPACE. I'm just doing what I found in https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: it looks surely a version issue: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go#compiling-error-undefined-grpcsupportpackageisversion

---

Not a bazel user, but after hours' test, I found your rpc version should be higher:

```
 go_repository(
     name = "org_golang_google_grpc",
-    build_file_proto_mode = "disable",
     importpath = "google.golang.org/grpc",
-    sum = "h1:J0UbZOIrCAl+fpTOf8YLs4dJo8L/owV4LYVtAXQoPkw=",
-    version = "v1.22.0",
+    sum = "h1:f+PlOh7QV4iIJkPrx5NQ7qaNGFQ3OTse67yaDHfju4E=",
+    version = "v1.41.0",
 )
```

Then you can build it:

```
 ~/code/example-go-grpc (main*) [09:45:55]
p1gd0g$ bazel build //examples/grpc/protos:helloworld_go_proto
INFO: Analyzed target //examples/grpc/protos:helloworld_go_proto (49 packages loaded, 306 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target //examples/grpc/protos:helloworld_go_proto up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/examples/grpc/protos/helloworld_go_proto.a
INFO: Elapsed time: 41.180s, Critical Path: 1.20s
INFO: 29 processes: 1 internal, 28 linux-sandbox.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 29 total actions
```

And I recommend using gazelle with go.mod to generate WORKSPACE. A demo: https://github.com/p1gd0g/helloworld